# Other elementary question about image and preimage of relations.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Hi everyone I continue working with set theory. I'm really stuck with some exercise. I thought to have the answer but I tried to give an example and is different than I proved.

The problem is to prove the next two statements and give some counterexample for what the equality doesn't hold.

(1) $R^{-1}[\,R[\,A\,]\,] \supseteq A \cap \mathscr{D}(R)\,$ ( where $\mathscr{D}(R)$ is the domain of the relation ).

Proof:

($\,\Rightarrow\,$) Suppose $x\in A \cap \mathscr{D}(R).$ So, $x\in \mathscr{D}(R)$ iff there is a $y$ such that $\langle x,y \rangle \in R.$ Then there is an $x\in A$ such that $\langle x,y \rangle \in R,$ therefore $y\in R[\,A\,].$ Symmetrically, there is an $y\in R[\,A\,]$  such that $\langle x,y \rangle \in R,$ therefore $x \in R^{-1}[\,R[\,A\,]\,],$ as desired.

($\,\Leftarrow\,$) Now suppose $x\in R^{-1}[\,R[\,A\,]\,].$ Then there exist some $y\in R[\,A\,]$ such that $\langle x,y \rangle \in R.$ On the other hand, $y\in  R[\,A\,] $ if there exist an $x'\in A$ such that $\langle x',y \rangle \in R.$

***Assume the property:*** $\,x\,R\,y \text{ and } x'\,R\,y$ implies $x=x'.$

Therefore $x\in A$ and also, as $x\,R\,y$ it follows that $x\in \mathscr {D} (R)$.
Hence, $x \in A \cap \mathscr {D} (R).$

So, as I proved (assuming that is correct) the equality holds using an extra-property. But if a give the next example where the property does not hold:

$A: = \left\{\, x, x^{*}, x^{**}\, \right\} \text { and } R:= \left\{ \langle x,y \rangle, \langle x^{*},y \rangle \right\}.$

$A \cap \mathscr{D}(R) = \left\{\, x, x^{*} \,\right\} \text{ and } R^{-1}[\,R[\,A\,]\,] = R^{-1} [\left\{\,y \, \right\}] = \left\{\, x, x^{*} \,\right\}  $

So, I am not assuming the necessary property but the equality holds. My question is: where is wrong my reasoning?

As always thanks in advanced.

---

Sorry I forgot to put the statement 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what you are looking for, since the set on which the relation $R$ lives has not been identified. But the following example may settle your problem.

Let $X$ be say the $3$-element set $\{a,b,c\}$. Define a relation $R$ on $X$ by saying that $xRy$ holds if $y=a$, and $x$ is anything.  Let $A=\{a\}$.

Then $A \cap \mathscr{D}(R)=A=\{a\}$. But $R^{-1}[\,R[\,A\,]\,]=X$.

Comment: Thank you. So, I think I confused myself. On the other hand, do you think that the proof is correct?

Comment: In the first part, I can see what you are getting at, would write it a bit differently. Take an element $x$ of the right-hand side. Then $x$ in in $A$ and in the domain of $R$. So there is a $y$ such that $xRy$. Now finish as you did, saying that $y$ in in $R[A]$ and therefore $x$ is in $R^{-1}[R[A]]$. As you point out the unique inverse property is enough to prove equality in the other direction. But **failure** of unique inverse does not imply that equality fails.

Comment: So that was my problem, I assumed that if the unique inverse property fails, therefore the equality does not hold. I have a question is  there a property which guarantees that the equality does not hold or I need to look for examples where that happens? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: One could cook up an if and only if condition involving uniqueness of inverses. I am not sure it is worth formulating.